# Strange haproxy behaviour

Tags: ubuntu, networking, haproxy, high-availability, ubuntu-14.04

I'm trying to set up a dual site haproxy (1.5.10) on Ubuntu 14.04.

[image]

When I do `service heartbeat restart` on eartha, both machines go green briefly; then earthb goes yellow -> red!

When I do `service heartbeat restart` on earthb, both machines go green briefly; then eartha goes yellow -> red!

It's as if a restart on one machine knocks out the other???

All firewalls are currently disabled.

Here is the setup:

**virtual IP**: 131.43.93.207

**eartha**: 131.43.93.212 (eth0), 10.100.100.71 (eth1)

**earthb**: 131.43.93.214 (eth0), 10.100.100.72 (eth1)

Here's eartha's configuration (mirror image for earthb):

ifconfig -a

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:21:32:a0  
          inet addr:131.43.93.212  Bcast:131.43.93.255  Mask:255.255.254.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe11:25a0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:926969 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:358004 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:105321152 (105.3 MB)  TX bytes:70526466 (70.5 MB)

eth0:0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:21:32:a0  
          inet addr:131.43.93.207  Bcast:131.43.93.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:21:32:a1  
          inet addr:10.100.100.71  Bcast:10.100.100.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe11:25a1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:95069 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:73007 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:27324681 (27.3 MB)  TX bytes:24610741 (24.6 MB)

global
        log /dev/log    local0
        log /dev/log    local1 notice
        chroot /var/lib/haproxy
        stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin
        stats timeout 30s
        user haproxy
        group haproxy
        daemon

        # Default SSL material locations
        ca-base /etc/ssl/certs
        crt-base /etc/ssl/private

        # Default ciphers to use on SSL-enabled listening sockets.
        # For more information, see ciphers(1SSL).
        ssl-default-bind-ciphers kEECDH+aRSA+AES:kRSA+AES:+AES256:RC4-SHA:!kEDH:!LOW:!EXP:!MD5:!aNULL:!eNULL
        ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3
        tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048
defaults
        log     global
        mode    http
        option  httplog
        option  dontlognull
        timeout connect 5000
        timeout client  50000
        timeout server  50000
        errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
        errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
        errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
        errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
        errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
        errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
        errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http
listen pithos
        bind 131.43.93.207:80
        bind 131.43.93.207:443 ssl crt /etc/apache2/ssl/combined.pem ciphers TLSv1+HIGH:!SSLv2:RC4+MEDIUM:!aNULL:!eNULL:!3DES:@STRENGTH
        mode http
        stats enable
        stats uri /haproxy?stats
        stats realm Strictly\ Private
        stats auth admin:xxx
        balance roundrobin
        option http-server-close
        timeout http-keep-alive 3000
        option forwardfor
        cookie JSESSIONID insert
        server eartha 131.43.93.212:8080 cookie eartha check
        server earthb 131.43.93.214:8080 cookie earthb check

        redirect scheme https code 302 if !{ ssl_fc }
```

/etc/ha.d/haresources

```
eartha IPaddr::131.43.93.207/24/eth0 apache2
```

/etc/ha.d/ha.cf

```
watchdog            /dev/watchdog
logfile             /var/log/ha-log
debugfile           /var/log/ha-debug
deadtime            5
warntime            10
initdead            15
bcast               eth1
auto_failback       on
node                eartha
node                earthb
```

Comment: Please, for the love of all that is good and holy, do not use Heartbeat. The whole Heartbeat stack has been obsoleted many years ago by the Corosync/Pacemaker combo, for various reasons, among them the many conceptual shortcomings of Heartbeat. And in your case you don't even need a real Cluster Resource Manager to implement a highly available HAProxy setup. Instead look into Keepalived, which is also what [the creator of HAProxy recommends](http://www.formilux.org/archives/haproxy/1003/3259.html). We've successfully been running many HAProxy+Keepalived setups in production for years now.

Comment: Thank you for your tip. I feel like such a n00b here... I'm going to reinstall everything from scratch with HAProxy + Keepalived this time.

Comment: You should also strongly consider not using Ubuntu. But that's another discussion...

Comment: Working fine with keepalived... So much easier. Your experienced eye was of huge help, thanks

Comment: Briefly, why not use Ubuntu? Thank you,